# Autoincrementing based on previous entry in Sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I am creating a web-based POS system.  Once the users clicks the "order submit" the each item is sent to the sqlite db with this schema:

```
drop table if exists orders;
create table orders (
    transaction_id integer primary key autoincrement,
    total_price integer not null,
    SKU integer not null,
    product_name text not null,
    unit_price integer not null,
    quantity integer not null
);
```

Through this flask code:

```
@app.route('/load_ajax', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def load_ajax():
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = request.get_json()
        for group in groupby(data, itemgetter('name')):
            id, data_list = group
            for d in data_list:
                print d['subtotal']
                db = get_db()
                order = db.execute('insert into orders (total_price, SKU, product_name, unit_price, quantity) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
                [d['subtotal'], d['sku'], d['name'], d['price'], d['quantity']])
                db.commit()
        return jsonify(location=url_for('thankyou'))
```

When I initially created the schema I thought that `transaction_id integer primary key autoincrement` would be sufficient for a transaction id (an id that is attached to every item in the order), but kind of forgot that there could be multiple items in the order.  So now, every item get's it's own primary key, which is not what I wanted.  A sqlite3 output for one order looks like this:

```
1|61.45|ASD|Hot Sauce|10.99|1
2|61.45|JKL|Chilli Peppers|8.99|1
3|61.45|UIO|Sip 'n' Sizzle T-Shirt|10.5|1
```

and I would like everything in the first column to just be 1.  Is there anything I can do to my schema to get my desired action?  I'm not really sure on the best way to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

Normalize your database.
Put all repeating information into one table, and all information that changes for each item into another table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE orders (
    transaction_id integer primary key autoincrement,
    total_price integer not null
);
CREATE TABLE order_items (
    transaction_id integer REFERENCES orders(transaction_id),
    SKU integer not null,
    product_name text not null,
    unit_price integer not null,
    quantity integer not null
);
```

Comment: So, I'm trying to change my flask code.  Do I need to do two db.executes or can that all happen on one line?